# Написал программу но ее блочат антивирусы

Tags: python, компиляция, exe, антивирус

Написал простейшую программу. После компиляции в экзешник антивирус ставит ее в критическую угрозу и удаляет с компа. Покупать лицуху за 100 баксов или писать всем антивирусам в мире не особо горю желанием. Может если кто то сталкивался, знает как решить проблему?

Короче для тех кому надо: https://gist.github.com/ParanoikTemp/28fdb5113610d7e85e883863803890cd

Comment: Приведите свой код

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Тут дело не в коде, я думаю, так что приводить его необязательно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну хз, видел случаи, когда подтягивали всю либу, а использовали один метод из нее. И антивирусы ругались на сомнительные методы, которые даже не использовались.

Comment: А какие технологии вы используете? Сеть? Перехвать? Инжекцию? Службы? Драйвера? Запуск внешних программ? То выходит хороший вопрос, у меня есть программа - угадайте почему её мочат антивирусы. Бейте программу на модули, отключайте все и по одному включайте - так найдёте что не нравится антивирусу.

Comment: А зачем вообще "компилировать программу"?

Comment: @nick_n_a прога тупейшая и никаких перехватов и т.д. Писал на питоне. Использовал только eel из модулей.

Comment: @nick_n_a какая тебе нужна информация?

Comment: @nick_n_a вот код программы https://gist.github.com/ParanoikTemp/28fdb5113610d7e85e883863803890cd

Comment: С английской версии советы пробовали, или не получается понять что там написано? Особенно то что про версии https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054580/5727271 и там где иконку к приложению добавить?